# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, selenium, java-7, selenium-grid

I am trying to run `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar` with command as below

```
java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -role hub
```

But while running i am getting an exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
    org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

My Java versions are as below:
[image]

And My `Path` Variable has below entry:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\
```

Where am i lagging? Is there any specific version needed for `Selenium 3.0`

Comment: well do you think that maybe this version of selenium has been compiled for some other version?

Comment: @ScaryWombat .. that is what i am not sure of

Comment: well did you download it?  It probably gives such information on the download page

Comment: I did download it and searched for JDK compatible witht his.. but did not get any info.. and about Duplicate: i am not sure if it is duplicate as i have updated all things.. even then someone has downvoted and marked a duplicated... not true

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson ... can u explain how u marked it as duplicated?

Comment: * Minimum java version is now 8+
Always refer to the change log before upgrading to new version.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG